# Gating an astable 555 output signal in a way that oscilation always starts with a Low to High transition

Tags: 555, astable

simply, the circuit is a 38KHz signal generator for an IR remote project. the output signal should be gated by an MCU according to IR timing intervals recorded earlier. the design with the 4148 diode is for duty cycle control.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKe2db.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

first, I tried the left section (simple gating) alone. it worked but the timings were a little (up to 30 us) offset in randomly both directions.

-- *I deduced the problem may be that the gated signal, may start at any point of wave, not essentially at a low to high transition.*

then, I used the right hand section to override trigger/threshold. so when the input gating signal is low, the threshold is kept high, the capacitor stays charged and output (and IRLED) is forced low.
when the Gate signal goes high, the reverse story happens.

the problem is, the timings are a lot more (up to milliseconds) distorted in this case. so here are the obvious questions :

1. is the deduced idea of bad behavior correct ?
2. is the suggested solution correct ?
3. in case of "NO" for the previous questions, is there any idea how to do that on a 555 (or similar one chip, general purpose oscillator) ?

*the output signals out of MCU are correct.*
*can't use mcu for 38khz signal generation.*

Comment: You have a microcontroller already there.  Why not use a timer in the controller to generate the 38kHz signal?  Start up is then clearly defined, and you have less finicky analog hardware to fiddle with.

Comment: I would free run the 555 and then gate the clock; this can be done with quite a simple circuit.

Comment: @JRE it's a constraint.

Comment: @PeterSmith that's exactly what I did at first. (Its written just after the circuit image.)

Comment: Why do you have the constraint of needing the IR signal to start with a low high transition? This is hugely complicating the solution. Give us more detail about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RoyC for the transition thing, imagine a sample part the IR timing says 420us low. So after  the first 38khz burst, we have to wait 300us and send another 38khz for a specific duration. If the next 38khz dont start at a LtoH, then we have 300 + 26 us instead.

Comment: @RoyC for the mcu thing, it's a library to be portable to any mcu with a timer with, regardless of timer output capability. Generally the question  much about the 555 itself than the mcu and IR thing.

Comment: The timer on your controller doesn't need an output.  The timer only has to trigger an interrupt routine.  The interrupt routine can then drive the outputs as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you **must** use the 555, and a simple gate circuit isn't adequate (the IR burst **must** always start with a low to high transition,)  then you need to synchronize the gate with the 555 state.

Your microcontroller has other inputs.  Use one to detect the state of the 555.

Now, when the controller needs to turn on the IR burst, it first checks the state of the 555 and waits for the 555 to go low.  Then the controller turns on the gate.

Depending on how fast the controller is, you may need to use interrupts to detect the state and switch fast enough to meet other timing requirements.

---

The gating could also be done in discrete logic (and gates, flip flops, and such,) but you have the controller there already.  Whether you'd rather write more software or build more hardware is your choice.

---

Alternatively, try some of the [reset circuits for the 555 given on this linked site.](https://www.electroschematics.com/7195/quirky-555-timer-reset-function/)

Ideally, you would pull the RESET pin low to stop the oscillator then let it go high to start again.

Apparently, though, the 555 reset pin is somewhat buggy so that it is neccessary to use alternative methods to get the desired function.

Or just, you know, generate your IR signal directly in your controller like any reasonable engineer would instead of lashing a 555 circuit together and trying to brow beat it into functioning.

Maybe the assignment is just that:  a lesson in just how ugly it is to mix discrete analog circuits with microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Connect the gate signal into the 555's reset pin, so that the 555 is in a known state every time the gate goes high.

The gate doesn't even need to connect to the transistor it can be omitted, with the LED driven directly by the 555 output (though I would add a resistor).

The output is low if reset is low, so your gate off condition means that there is no output if the gate is low.

Comment: In the reset the cap is chqrged. The charged cap, ensures the low to high transition, but only after a full LOW half cycle because the threshold pin is kept high. So we have an offset of half cycle and the problem exists.